# PyGTK: How can I reference a Button in a Dialog when added from the constructor?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk, gtk3

I'm using PyGTK (gtk3) to make a Dialog. If I use `Gtk.MessageDialog` and declare a button in the constructor, how do I reference that button in order to attach a call back to its events?

For example:

```
Gtk.MessageDialog(None, Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL, Gtk.MessageType.INFO, Gtk.ButtonsType.OK, "MY TEXT!")
```

Comment: If nothing else you should be able to reach the button via a chain of get_children calls

Comment: @deinonychusaur, thanks. That's what I'm using so far.

Comment: `gtk_dialog_get_widget_for_response()`? I believe the names in the `Gtk.ButtonsType` enumeration map to the names in the `Gtk.ResponseType` enumeration, but I'm not 100% sure. Best guess I can give for now, anyway...

Comment: Are you sure you need to access the button? the dialog response should be all you need...

Comment: @jku, the default behaviour when I click the button is nothing. The dialog remains where it is (still open).

Comment: @JellicleCat yes, you are supposed to handle the response,  either using the 'response'  signal or using the return value from dialog.run() if you use that.

Comment: @jku, thanks. I didn't even notice that `dialog.run()` blocked or returned, but now I see it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

you can also get all widgets that is in a dialog by `vbox` widget.

```
msg_dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog(None, Gtk.DialogFlags.MODAL, Gtk.MessageType.INFO, Gtk.ButtonsType.OK, "MY TEXT!")
print msg_dialog.vbox.get_children()
```